# Firebase not recording installation referrer

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to add install-attribution to a React Native android app.  I believe I'm firing the event correctly in dev mode, but I don't actually see the event in the firebase debug log, or in the conversion.  I can see other analytics events, just not this one.

I added this to `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Watch the logs:

```
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
$ adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Broadcast the message:

```
$ adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=medium&utm_medium=test&utm_content=reactnativetest&utm_campaign=reactnativetest"
```

The logs seem show a "successful upload":

```
04-09 11:05:04.314 V/FA      ( 7426): Local receiver got: com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
04-09 11:05:04.315 I/FA      ( 7426): Install referrer extras are: utm_source=medium
04-09 11:05:04.317 W/FA      ( 7426): Install referrer is missing timestamp
04-09 11:05:04.318 I/FA      ( 7426): Install Referrer Reporter is initializing
04-09 11:05:04.325 I/FA      ( 7426): Install Referrer Service is: available
04-09 11:05:04.330 V/FA      ( 7426): Install campaign recorded
04-09 11:05:04.338 D/FA      ( 7426): Logging event (FE): firebase_campaign(_cmp), Bundle[{click_timestamp=1554755627203, source=medium, firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1234512345123451234, campaign_info_source(_cis)=referrer broadcast}]
04-09 11:05:04.362 V/FA      ( 7426): Connecting to remote service
04-09 11:05:04.373 D/FA      ( 7426): Connected to remote service
04-09 11:05:04.373 V/FA      ( 7426): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
04-09 11:05:04.388 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Logging event: origin=auto,name=firebase_campaign(_cmp),params=Bundle[{click_timestamp=1554755627203, source=medium, firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1234512345123451234, campaign_info_source(_cis)=referrer broadcast}]
04-09 11:05:04.397 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Saving event, name, data size: firebase_campaign(_cmp), 147
04-09 11:05:04.398 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example', name='firebase_campaign(_cmp)', params=Bundle[{click_timestamp=1554755627203, source=medium, firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, _r=1, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1234512345123451234, campaign_info_source(_cis)=referrer broadcast, _dbg=1}]}
04-09 11:05:04.399 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 500
04-09 11:05:04.400 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
04-09 11:05:04.403 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Scheduling upload with DelayedRunnable
04-09 11:05:04.404 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
04-09 11:05:04.404 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 500
04-09 11:05:04.409 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Background event processing time, ms: 21
04-09 11:05:04.662 I/FA      ( 7426): Install Referrer Service connected
04-09 11:05:04.679 E/FA      ( 7426): Service response is missing Install Referrer install timestamp
04-09 11:05:04.907 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
04-09 11:05:04.910 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Starting upload from DelayedRunnable
04-09 11:05:04.918 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Saving bundle, size: 505
04-09 11:05:04.919 D/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 512
04-09 11:05:04.921 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.example, 546,
...
04-09 11:05:04.921 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
04-09 11:05:04.923 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Uploading data. size: 519
04-09 11:05:05.149 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599995
04-09 11:05:05.151 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
04-09 11:05:05.157 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
04-09 11:05:05.157 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 3599995
04-09 11:05:05.160 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
04-09 11:05:05.164 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
04-09 11:05:05.165 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
04-09 11:05:05.169 V/FA-SVC  ( 8508): Stopping uploading service(s)
```

In Firebase under "Conversions", I can see that `first_open` is set to "Mark as conversion".  However, the data only shows `google-play`, `(direct)` and `google` as sources.

Also, I can see "screen_view" and "user_engagement" events in the Firebase `DebugView` when I turn it on, but nothing related to the referrer attribution.

I'm not sure what the problem is---does it need to be a Google campaign?  (Ultimately I want to track facebook campaigns.)  Or does it need to be installed from the Play store?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, @mikebridge?

Comment: @Bataleon I was using a com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver and AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver, saving them to asyncstorage, then retrieving them later, but I'm told the latest update has broken this somehow.